# queryBuilder create sql with innerJoin

Tags: sql, symfony

i can't to do true query from 2 tables.

```
   /**
 * Order
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="order_work")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\OrderWorkRepository")
 */
class OrderWork
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="orderNumber", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $orderNumber;
```

and client entity have id, name, surname parameters:

I want to do search by orders column, and by client parameters how i can which query?)

only for orders work this:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->orWhere('c.orderNumber LIKE :term')
        ->orWhere('c.device LIKE :term')
        ->setParameter('term', '%'.$term.'%');
```

Comment: I've already spent a few minutes going over your question and it's not very clear. Can you please edit your question and add more details on what is needed? See [how to ask a question for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I'm giving you -1 until you update. Also in your createQueryBuilder you specify an alias of 'c' - why. Does that represent `OrderWork`? But for `OrderWork` you don't have a column of `device`! So what do you really want to query?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a query with a join, which is possible with the querybuilder but i like to use DQL.

```
public function findOrdersOnClientName($searchTerm)
{
     return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT o, c FROM AppBundle:OrderWork o
        JOIN o.client c
        WHERE c.name LIKE :term'
    )->setParameter('term, '%'. $searchTerm . '%')->getResult();
}
```